# void Awake () doesn't execute in Android, Unity 3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, networking, 3d

I am trying to execute `Awake()` function on Android but something is going wrong.

This is networking app, and everything wroks perfectly but what I want to do is when app launches on Android device, it connects with server automatically as Client with no screen touching:

```
public class Automatic_Client : NetworkBehaviour {

    public NetworkManager manager;

    public void Awake()
    {   
        if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
            manager.StartClient ();
```

If I change condition for WindowsEditor and try it on PC it works fine, but it doesn't in Android. When I Debug it on Android, it seems that void Awake() executes after choosing "`LAN Client`" from HUD by touching screen... It also doesn't work in `void Start()`. Help Pls!

`Unity 5.4, Android 6.0.1`

Comment: Awake can't be use as coroutine, if your manager.Startclient is a new thread or coroutine this will cause error.

Comment: @joreldraw Why are you talking about coroutine and thread? I don't think it is relevant since OP did not mention they were being used.

Comment: Are the behaviour and its parent GameObject enabled at startup? Awake() will only run once it is enabled.

Comment: @Programmer because sure they use a thread or coroutine to manage the autoconnection, timeouts, retry, etc. And can't work if called from Awake. Awake is only to initialize values that you need on Start.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it could be you have set `Awake()` as public. I would leave it declared as private/no qualifier on it to see if that helps.

Otherwise you could try using `Start()` instead of `Awake()`, or make a public `Initialize()` function you call from your starting script.